# Who Work or Who Works

Tags: grammar

Here's the thing. 
I do know what it's right to use the S form for verbs when the subject IS, he, she and etc. So i always believed when you use 'who' you should put nothing but -s in the end of the verbs as well. But there was a couple times when I heard how people dropped S in cases where before 'who' was plural noun and so on.

What is correct? Should I use S or not after Who.

Example:

**The ones** who **work** for this company.*

I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Who* can be singular or plural:

> The man who works for me is tall.
>
> The men who work for me are smart.

The verb agrees with the number that *who* represents. When it is singular, it takes a singular verb (usually with an -s ending), when plural, the plural form (no -s).